# How to set a right revolute joint coordinate?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Okay guys, im trying to use gazebo to simulate my simple arm but i'm stuck at second joint.
Idk why, but it rotates based on some other axis(or some other coordination).

the arm is at the right place when i don't move them,  so changing  coordinate would changes arm's position.
i want to keep my arm that position and want to rotate based on the shaft( black horn with green part).

anyone had a same problem and solved it?
what i am thinking about is that i change joint coordinate and changes link's visual coordinate.
but i am not sure this is the right way to solve this problem.
Help me guy **thx!**

https://github.com/benthebear93/clime_robot/blob/master/v4_robot/urdf/v4_robot.urdf
Here is my robot's urdf, and u could see the package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23560/how-to-set-a-right-revolute-joint-coordinate?/) by [benthebear93](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14893/benthebear93/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can right-click your model and select `View -> Transparent` then `View -> Joints` to see where the joint axis currently is. Then I would suggest you change your link and joint `<origin>`s on URDF until the axis shows up in the correct place (on top of the green part).

Visualizing link frames with `View -> Link Frames` should also help you.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benthebear93](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14893/benthebear93/) on 2019-08-22**:
didn't know there is link visualization! i will try that thx !!

**Comment by [benthebear93](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14893/benthebear93/) on 2019-08-23**:
thx! i solved it. it save a lot of my time really appropriate